# MapViewOfFile read from a given position

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, mapping, c++17

I need to read a large file in parts to a limited buffer. My code works, but always reads from the beginning. I think I need to use dwFileOffsetHigh somehow and dwFileOffsetLow, but I can't figure out how. Mapper_Winapi_Uptr is a unique_ptr with a custom deleter, if necessary I can lay out its code. 
System: 64bit Win10.

```
const std::vector<BYTE>& ReadFile(size_t pos) {

    memory = Mapper_Winapi_Uptr{ static_cast<BYTE*>(MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, bufferSize)) };
    std::memcpy(&data[0], memory.get(), bufferSize);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) explain how those parameters are used. What are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: I read the documentation but did not understand the difference between these parameters and how to use them.

Comment: The file offset is a 64 bit value, split into two 32 bit values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping the view at file offset 0, ignoring your `pos` parameter which is presumably the desired file offset.

`MapViewOfFile()` takes a 64bit offset as input, split into 32bit low and high values.  A `size_t` may be a 32bit or 64bit type, depending on compiler and platform. You can put your desired offset into a `ULARGE_INTEGER` first, that will give you the low and high values you can then give to `MapViewOfFile()`.

Note that the file offset you give to `MapViewOfFile()` must be a multiple of the system allocation granularity. See [Creating a View Within a File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-view-within-a-file) on MSDN for details on how to handle that.

Try something like this:

```cpp
SYSTEM_INFO SysInfo;
GetSystemInfo(&SysInfo);
DWORD SysGran = SysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
... 
const std::vector<BYTE>& ReadFile(size_t pos)
{
    size_t MapViewStart = (pos / SysGran) * SysGran;
    DWORD MapViewSize = (pos % SysGran) + bufferSize;
    DWORD ViewDelta = pos - MapViewStart;

    ULARGE_INTEGER ulOffset;
    ulOffset.QuadPart = MapViewStart;
    memory = Mapper_Winapi_Uptr{ static_cast<BYTE*>(MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, ulOffset.HighPart, ulOffset.LowPart, bufferSize)) };
    if (!memory.get()) {
        // error handling ...
    }

    std::memcpy(&data[0], &(memory.get())[ViewDelta], bufferSize);
    return data;
}
```